# Greek prefix for zero - any examples?

Tags: greek, prefixes

Wikipedia states that the greek prefixes for zero are

- meden-
- ouden-

Any examples in a modern language? (preferably spanish)

Comment: There is a proposal to create a Greek Language stackexchange, you can support it by adding your question as an example and/or upvoting the other questions: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not a lot. The obvious place to start is Modern Greek :-) , and even there, there's just words corresponding to Latin nihil- words:

- μηδενιστής "nihilist" (obviously a recent calque)
- μηδενίζω "to give a zero grade; to dismiss as worthless; to clock a counter" (also looks to be recent)
- ουδενίζω, oυδενόω "to annihilate" (shows up in Patristic Greek)

Ancient Greek does have οὐδενία "worthlessness" (in Plato) and οὐδενόσωρος "nobody's concern = worthless" (in Homer).

Comment: Καλως ηρθες, δάσκαλε!

Comment: Καλώς σε βρήκα!